# Automatically rebase Merge Request branch when target branch has changed

Tags: automation, gitlab, build-automation, rebase

We have several simultaneously open merge requests targeting the same branch (usually master), all waiting for the test pipeline to succeed and getting merged automatically. Everyone hopes to be the first, because whenever one of the merge requests have been merged every Merge Request branch is out of date. To have them running their tests again we have to rebase all branches of the open merge requests manually. Usually every developer does this on his own on his machine or by using the green rebase button per Merge Request:

[image: Rebase button on Gitlab GUI]

Then the fight starts again and everyone hopes to be the first one. The biggest problem here is that when the developer doesn't notice that a Merge Request needs a rebase the actual merge is delayed and thus will most probably delay other Merge Requests as a direct result.

**Is there a possibility to have Gitlab rebasing all open Merge Request branch automatically after an update of the targeted branch?** The goal would be to have the Merge Requests getting tested again without having to manually rebase them, so we don't use time.

If that problem is solved the next step would be to preserve the automatic merge option along rebase actions:

[image: "Merge when pipeline succeeds" button on Gitlab GUI]

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible.

There is an issue (closed with some very recent comments) about it https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/18834

Reading the entire issue, one of the developers said that he is working on something similar https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/895  but this will not solve your problem